# How to wait function call return value before go to the next line in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, synchronous, sendasynchronousrequest

I have two functions **is_exist()** and **save()** functions.
In save function I calls **is_exist()** function before performing a save.it return boolean value.
but my problem is **save()** function is not wait until **is_exist()** function to return the value.after **is_exist()** function called it just jump into next line and continue execute bellow lines, after **save()** finished **is_exist()** function return the value

```
var app = angular.module('my_app', [])
app.controller('my_con', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.save = function(sector) {
        var del_status = $scope.is_exist(sector);

        console.log(del_status); // is_exsis return value

        if(!del_status) {
            // save
        }
    }

    $scope.is_exist = function(sector) {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/is_data_exist',
            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data : angular.toJson({
                'sector': sector
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            console.log(response.data); //http respond

            if(response.data == 'False') {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        })
    }
}])
```

is there any way to wait until **is_exsis()** function to return value and then go to next line

Comment: it is asynchronous, it means you "can't", because you don't know when the promise will be resolved. What you can do is pass the following code as a function to your promise, so that the promise executes it. something like `var del_status = $scope.is_exist(sector, function(){ console.log(del_status); /* etc */ });` (be careful, you have a typo, exist != exsis)

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: @Nevosis [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1) your link is about ajax and my question is about angularjs

Comment: My link and your question is about asynchronous call in javascript. It is the exact same thing in angular, react, ajax, jquery, nodejs, etc... How to handle async call in js ? Mainly promises and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `callback` function in `$scope.is_exsis(sector);` and perform this action inside callback function -

```
 var del_status = $scope.is_exsis(function(data){
    console.log(del_status); // is_exsis return value

    if(!del_status) {
        // save
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to return the Promise and then chain it so that the save isn't completed until is_exists is done.

```
$scope.save = function(sector) {
    $scope.is_exsis(sector).then(function(del_status){

        console.log(del_status); // is_exsis return value

        if(!del_status) {
        // save
        }
   });

}

$scope.is_exist = function(sector) {
    return $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/is_data_exist',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data : angular.toJson({
            'sector': sector
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        console.log(response.data); //http respond

        if(response.data == 'False') {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    })
}
```